# Installed Prestashop Theme not found in folder

Tags: php, themes, prestashop

I want to uninstall a Prestashop theme. However when I go to the theme folder, there isnt any folder of the theme. 
Is there a way to return to the default setting?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you use PrestaShop 1.5 and you see the theme you want to delete on your backoffice.

How this theme has been installed ?

The theme name displayed in the backoffice is stored in the DB, if the theme relative folder doesn't exist in the "/themes" folder, you can safely delete the entry in the backoffice.